# what would be java.naming.provider.url for tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I m trying to fetch a database connection from a tomcat server using Jndi. In that case what would be my java.naming.provider.url in case of tomcat ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't very clear.  Per the JNDI [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jndi/jndi-rmi.html#URLPROP), the url property specifies the location of the registry in the format rmi://server:port.  So at least when you're initially creating a naming context to bindings for the objects registered in the registry, you need to pass in the location of the registry.  You can find sample code [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/jndi/index.html):

```
// select the registry service provider as the initial context
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory");

// specify where the registry is running
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "rmi://server:1099");

// create an initial context that accesses the registry
Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);

// now, the names stored in registry can be listed
NamingEnumeration enum = ctx.list("");
```