# Initialcontext in a standalone Java program

Tags: java, jndi

I'm using a JNDI for creating connection pool. It works great in a web application. I believe the InitialContext is provided by the tomcat server.

```
Context initContext  = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/testdb");
```

But when I try to call the same utility from a standalone Java program, the initContext object  is null. How can I explicitly provide all the necessary properties that Context object is expecting.

> Error : javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class
> name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or
> in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also create your own custom context.

```
LocalContext ctx = LocalContextFactory.createLocalContext();
ctx.addDataSource("jdbc/testdb", driverName, url, usr, pwd);
```

See [*Running Beans Locally that use Application Server Data Sources*](http://penguindreams.org/blog/running-beans-that-use-application-server-datasources-locally/) for more details.

---

[image: new] *UPDATE*

You can use the class [**`org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContextBuilder`**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/mock/jndi/SimpleNamingContextBuilder.html) of Spring. e.g.:

- *Setup:*

  ```
  SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
  builder.bind("jdbc/Oracle", ods);
  builder.activate();
  ```
- *Use:*

  ```
  DataSource ds = InitialContext.doLookup("jdbc/Oracle");
  ```

Comment: Please note, as the last comments of the article you linked indicated that the solutions is buggy: A StackOverflowException is thrown during the lookup if the name is null or not found...

Comment: Really nice. Set save my test. I manipulate the context which was used in an implementation of an interface.

Comment: I am not using spring or any java EE technology. i still want to use local context at server startup.

Answer (score 28):

Here is an example adapted from the accepted answer but doing everything inline to avoid creating extra classes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    setupInitialContext();
    //do something that looks up a datasource
}

private static void setupInitialContext() {
    try {
        NamingManager.setInitialContextFactoryBuilder(new InitialContextFactoryBuilder() {

            @Override
            public InitialContextFactory createInitialContextFactory(Hashtable<?, ?> environment) throws NamingException {
                return new InitialContextFactory() {

                    @Override
                    public Context getInitialContext(Hashtable<?, ?> environment) throws NamingException {
                        return new InitialContext(){

                            private Hashtable<String, DataSource> dataSources = new Hashtable<>();

                            @Override
                            public Object lookup(String name) throws NamingException {

                                if (dataSources.isEmpty()) { //init datasources
                                    MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
                                    ds.setURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb");
                                    ds.setUser("mydbuser");
                                    ds.setPassword("mydbpass");
                                    dataSources.put("jdbc/mydbname", ds);

                                    //add more datasources to the list as necessary
                                }

                                if (dataSources.containsKey(name)) {
                                    return dataSources.get(name);
                                }

                                throw new NamingException("Unable to find datasource: "+name);
                            }
                        };
                    }

                };
            }

        });
    }
    catch (NamingException ne) {
        ne.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Congratulations! Optimal solution, clean and simple!

Comment: This saved me hours of scouring through Java's arcane APIs. Thank you!

Comment: This is NOT avoiding creating extra classes. This is creating several anonymous classes. Good luck testing any of this.

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own `Context` by sub-classing `javax.naming.InitialContext` and implementing only a small subset of methods, typically the `bind` and the `lookup` methods.

Then you can create your data source and bind it to your initial context to a specific key. After this you are ready to go and query from any place your JNDI context in your stand-alone Java programme.

This is the code you can use to create your own context:

```
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext() {

    private Map<String, Object> table = new HashMap<>();

    public void bind(String key, Object value) {
        table.put(key, value);
    }

    public Object lookup(String key) throws NamingException {
        return table.get(key);
    }
};

// Activate the initial context
NamingManager.setInitialContextFactoryBuilder(environment -> environment1 -> initialContext);
```

Then you can initialise your data source, whichever you choose:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
bds.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
bds.setUrl(url);
bds.setUsername(username);
bds.setPassword(password);

ic.bind(jndiPath, bds);
```

And somewhere else in your code, you can use the existing data source by retrieving it from the JNDI context:

```
InitialContext ic2 = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic2.lookup(jndiPath);
assertNotNull(ds);
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
assertNotNull(conn);
conn.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to directly use the Tomcat Context Factory, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jndi/jndi-rmi.html#URLPROP) for a little more documentation on the alternatives. But I recommend you try running a registry outside of Tomcat...

```
// select the registry context factory for creating a context
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory");

// specify where that factory is running.
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "rmi://server:1099");

// create an initial context that accesses the registry
Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
```

You could change your code in Tomcat to also use this external RegistryContext and then both set(s) would be using the same JNDI provider. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324989/what-would-be-java-naming-provider-url-for-tomcat) seems very similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a standalone app (or unit tests!) to use your server's `INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY` without running the server.

This is how to do that for a **Apache Tomcat** initialization, *but you should have enough information to adapt it for another server*.

**Starting configuration from the server**

This example presumes you want to mimic something like this from your `context.xml` file:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/testdb" auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
  username="someuser" password="somepassword"
  url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=somedb;applicationName=someapp"/>
```

**Create the resource to go into the Context**

This example is database specific, *but you can put things other than a `DataSource` in the Context*.  Here is one way you might be able to create a `DataSource` for this SQL Server example. (It requires the JDBC driver and `tomcat-dbcp.jar` in your classpath.  This code is for an older version of the driver, new versions probably have `SQLServerXADataSource` and would not need `tomcat-dbcp.jar`.)

```
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName(SQLServerDriver.class.getName());
dataSource.setUrl(url);
dataSource.setUsername(getUserName());
dataSource.setPassword(getPassword());
```

**Initialize using Tomcat INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY**

See [this old blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140530014804/https://blogs.oracle.com/randystuph/entry/injecting_jndi_datasources_for_junit).

```
System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
        "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.apache.naming");
InitialContext ctxt = new InitialContext();`
```

The reference to `org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory` means you should have `catalina.jar` in your classpath.  *You should be able to find variants for the `INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY` and `URL_PGK_PREFIXES` values for other application servers.*

**Register the resource for future lookups**

Then register your `DataSource dataSource` for future lookups, at `java:/comp/env/jdbc/testdb`.  Unfortunately, you have to make sure all the intermediate subcontext levels are created before you can add the resource. (Exercise for the reader: You can create a method to figure out the subcontext names from the `resourceName` instead of hard-coding the list as this example does.)

```
// Create all the intermediate levels
for (String resource : new String[]{ "java:", "java:comp", "java:comp/env", "java:/comp/env/jdbc" })
{
    try
    {
        ctxt.lookup(subContext);
    }
    catch (NameNotFoundException nnfe)
    {
        ctxt.createSubcontext(subContext);
    }
}

// Finally, register the resource
ctxt.bind(resourceName, dataSource);
```

This completes the setup portion, mimicking what is normally done in the Tomcat application server `context.xml`.

**Do the lookup**

Then the rest of your application can create `InitialContext`s and do `lookup`s as normal (in a single `lookup` call):

```
Context ic = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ic.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/testdb");
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat provides Context & DataSource implementations that work with the InitialContext class. When running Tomcat the Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY property is set to point to Tomcat's implementations. When not running Tomcat, you don't have this ability... you need to use a third-party-library like c3p0 for connection pooling.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an initial context using blow code.

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    // Retrieve the Home interface using JNDI lookup
    Object helloObject = ic.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/HelloBean");
```

if you want create custom initial context, you can extends javax.naming.InitailContext class