# Trouble running embedded Tomcat from IntelliJ Idea Community

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047860/tomcat-in-intellij-idea-community-edition) in order to run [this example](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/basic_app-tomcat-embedded.html#section2s1) from Oracle in  IntelliJ Idea Community Edition. I've created a new project, copied the source code from the example and enabled Maven support in Idea. I'm able to make and run the project but I can't access the service in the browser. Tomcat keeps throwing 404s. Note that the source code and pom.xml file are untouched.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.employees</groupId>
    <artifactId>employees-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>employees-app Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.57</tomcat.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
     <build>
        <finalName>employees-app</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <targetPath>META-INF/resources</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <finalName>employees-app-${project.version}</finalName>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.example.employees.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Using Process Monitor I've been able to determine that Tomcat associated the root of the website (localhost:8080) with MyProject\target\classes. If I place a dummy txt file in there I can access it via the browser (e.g. localhost:8080/test.txt).

The 'classes' directory is not empty. It contains two sub-directories:

1. com/example/employees/*.class - all the class files
2. META-INF/resources/[everything in /main/src/webapp in the [Oracle
   example ]](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/files/employees-app.zip)

My hunch is that there's something wrong with the folder hierarchy of the output. I'm not sure what or how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to run the example as explained in the official [doc](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/basic_app-tomcat-embedded.html#section9)? from command line (after mvn clean package), from the target folder run: java -jar employees-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar and then check on localhost:8080

Comment: No, I didn't. The objective is to be able to do Tomcat dev using IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

As the linked post indicates, it's best to use Heroku's launcher and pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.heroku.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>embeddedTomcatSample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>embeddedTomcatSample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.28</tomcat.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    ...tomcat & other deps...
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>embeddedTomcatSample</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>launch.Main</mainClass>
                        <name>webapp</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This launcher function does most of the magic by programatically configuring Tomcat to run inside the project's directory.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

        //The port that we should run on can be set into an environment variable
        //Look for that variable and default to 8080 if it isn't there.
        String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
        if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
            webPort = "8080";
        }

        tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

        StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" + webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

        // Declare an alternative location for your "WEB-INF/classes" dir
        // Servlet 3.0 annotation will work
        File additionWebInfClasses = new File("target/classes");
        WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(ctx);
        resources.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(resources, "/WEB-INF/classes",
                additionWebInfClasses.getAbsolutePath(), "/"));
        ctx.setResources(resources);

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
```

I couldn't figure out how to programatically set the path to Tomcat's *conf* folder but I was able to overcome this thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359483/initialcontext-in-a-standalone-java-program/21733896#comment57663464_21733896). Under normal circumstances, Tomcat takes care of setting up the initial context. As a result, the environment variables in a webapp's context.xml file end up in the initial context. Fortunately, it is possible to replicate this via a custom InitialContextFactory.