# No Initial Context Exception in j2ee

Tags: java, web.xml, context.xml

I am trying to do the connection pooling with `context.xml`
and `web.xml`.

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/project_1">

<Resource auth="Container"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    maxActive="100" maxIdle="30"
    maxWait="10000"
    name="connpool"
    password="oracle11"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523:system"
    username="system"/>
</Context>
```

**web.xml**

```
<resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>connpool</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

**Connection code**

```
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
Context context = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
// The JDBC Data source that we just created
DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("connpool");
this.con = ds.getConnection();
```

**Exception and stack trace**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at demo.main(demo.java:27)

C:\Users\BigGoal\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Could you try to name your resource 'jdbc/connpool' instead of 'connpool' ?

Answer (score 1):

Hemal , The default constructor will return you the context when you run the code on the server. When you have a standalone program , the default constructor will not return the IC. You will have to look at how to get the IC , you may want to set it

```
Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "rmi://server:1099");
InitialContext context = new InitialContext(env);
```

This is referenced [Tomcat book here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=c022aMuJBU4C&pg=PA452&lpg=PA452&dq=com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory%20tomcat&source=bl&ots=v_uIz1YyUL&sig=63N3f3djuviJIu3pWpoZLEoQR9c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQvvury-HOAhULRY8KHXdQAWEQ6AEIPjAF#v=onepage&q=com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory%20tomcat&f=false) and also in the [documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.7.0/docs/guide/jndi/jndi-rmi.html#URLPROP)

You may also want to refer this question here [Initialcontext in a standalone Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359483/initialcontext-in-a-standalone-java-program)

Hope it helps!